# Dynamic Programming Recursion

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a recursive method/function written in C# that get the max sum path of a 2d array with over 90 rows.  At about 25 rows the recursion stops.  I have tried to overcome the problem implementing an example made for a Fibonacci.  The result is, still the overflow but also the result is wrong.  This is what I have done and I thank you all for any solution or advise.

EDIT: Still not working with 90 rows.

```
static long[,] cache = new long[1000, 1000];
private long GetTotal(int row, int column, long[,] triangle, long[,] cache)
{
    if (row == 0) return triangle[row, column];

    long myValue = triangle[row, column];
    long left = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column, triangle, cache);
    long right = myValue + GetTotal(row - 1, column + 1, triangle, cache);

    if (cache[row, column] !=0)   
    return cache[row, column];

    cache[row, column] = Math.Max(left, right);
    return cache[row, column]; 
}
```

Comment: This code would be faster, safer and more readable if implemented as a loop. So what exactly did the recursion achieve?

Comment: Get the max path sum of a triangle in 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT cache based on row only, you should cache based on both row and column.

Your code as it is now stores one value for row, instead of multiple values per row, and one for each (row,column) combination.

Your 'key' for the cache should be (row,column). It could be solved using a 2D matrix - though it might be more expansive (in terms of weight) than a `Dictionary`.

Comment: So far you are the only one who knows what is talking about.#

Comment: I used array because I try to use an example on Fibonacci and still struggling with implementing Dictionary.

Comment: I just made some other change, but still not working with 90 rows.

Comment: In your previous Dictionary example you used Pair, which it should be a class.  There is another way without using creating a class?  Also, if I manage to make it work with a 2-d array I can replace it with a Dictionary.

Comment: @Orazio The point is you need a pair as a key. It can also work with `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,long>>` by getting `dictionary.get(row).get(column)` (I'd personally prefer a `Tuple`, but that's just me)> You can also use a 2D array - but it might cost more space if not done carefully.

Comment: I will try to work out something with Dictionary, but why with the 2-d array I have the same result? I am not sure it is an infinite recursive or overlaps.

Comment: Currently I solved with a iterative function and later I will try to work out Dynamic Programming.  Thank you.

Comment: Today I did some test and I found that the problem is not the number of rows but the amount of data to work with.  With 30 rows and random numbers 0-1000, fine, 99-1000 occur a kind of infinite recourse and 99-1 if fine.  I believe it is not about stack, since I never got a stack overflow exception but overlapping subproblems.